# sound hardware on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 installed on seperate partitioned hard drive. Xp Pro still on C drive.
I do not have sound on Windows 7. I worked on XP. I never got sound when I tried the Windows 7 RC Beta this past summer. Now that I have the new release installed...HOW DO I Get SOUND?

Answer (score 1):

Install the driver for it. Look up your computer on the manufacturer's website and get the Win 7 audio driver. If there isn't one, a Vista one should do.